# Como resolver problema da triangulação de Delaunay?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com um problema envolvendo triangulação de Delaunay. Preciso realizar uma triangulação de algumas circunferências. Entretanto, preciso retirar alguns triângulos que são inválidos pra mim, pois a triangulação é feita pelos centros da circunferências e eu preciso que seja feita pela área, para que as retas não passem por dentro das circunferências.

Segue o meu código:

```
# Triângulação dos pontos
# m_cylinders é um vetor que contem os centros das minhas circunferências
# m_raios é um vetor que contem os raios das circunferências 
    
tri = Delaunay(m_cylinders)
    
plt.triplot(m_cylinders[:,0], m_cylinders[:,1])
plt.plot(m_cylinders[:,0], m_cylinders[:,1], 'o')
    
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
    
vetor = tri.simplices
vetor_2 = m_cylinders[tri.simplices]
     
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for cir, rai in zip(m_cylinders,m_raios):
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((cir[0], cir[1]), rai,fill=False))
    
plt.plot([5,15,15,5,5],[0,0,4,4,0], linestyle='-', color='r',linewidth=1.0)
plt.triplot(m_cylinders[:,0], m_cylinders[:,1])
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')
ax.plot()
    
plt.show()
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nas bordas tem muitas circunferências em que as retas passam por dentro e isso pra mim não serve.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível solução para o seu problema é usar o algoritmo de triangulação de Delaunay com restrições. O algoritmo de triangulação de Delaunay com restrições permite que você especifique restrições sobre os triângulos gerados, como por exemplo, que as retas não devem passar por dentro das circunferências. Existem várias implementações deste algoritmo disponíveis, como o CGAL (Computational Geometry Algorithms Library) e o Triangle. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre estes algoritmos aqui:

CGAL: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html

Triangle: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake/triangle.html)